# Use local version of module from Github instead of installed

Tags: ruby

I am working on a project written in Ruby, which depends on another module using `require modulename`. I can change the required module to add the features I need, but I don't want to modify my installed version. I've downloaded the module from git, but I don't know how to point my project to this local version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the required module is a gem, you can use the [`path:` option in Gemfile](https://bundler.io/gemfile.html) to define a local version of a gem. So in Gemfile:

```rb
gem 'modulename', path: 'relative/path/to/modulename'
```

However, remember to remove the `path:` option before committing any changes to your git repository as you don't want that going into production.

Comment: And I assume then that ‘require modulename’ in the code would now point to the local version?